# How I can set type of column in update HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have this query, where I want edit one of the column:

```
update xx.xxx.Entity set :type = :data where id = :id
```

From **:type**, I want to put one of the option:
number/type/comment

But, I get this exception/error from IDEA : `<set assignment> expected, got ':'`

How can I do this?

Comment: please add the stack trace for your exception

Comment: sure, if it's help you: http://pastebin.com/z8vv6p9d

Comment: add your code please , make it more cleared

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hS1kpZpq

Comment: remove : 
try this update xx.xxx.Entity set type = :data where id = :id

Comment: but then, if I want to edit column 'comment', it's will be save to column type

Comment: you can not pass column name as a variable to the query

Comment: sorry, have to use an instance of

Comment: thank you, for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this syntax ?

```
@Query("update ru.mrchebik.model.TelephoneNumber set ?#{[0]} = :data where id = :id")
String editNumber(final String type, @Param("id") final long id, @Param("data") final String data);
```

Please, let's us know the result.

Comment: <set assignment> expected, got '?'

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?